# Wordpress Plugin "Contact Form 7 to Any API"

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, redirection-wordpress-plugin

Would any one be able to assist me with the following.
I have set up the above plugin to try and conect my contact form.
When testing the form sends the email to the directed inbox, however the "Contact Form 7 to Any API" plug in does not show log file, nore does the request hit my CRM.

Setting as set to

```
Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode( YOUR_USERNAME . ':' . YOUR_PASSWORD )
Content-Type: application/json
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Plug in details can be found here:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-to-any-api/

At this time I have tried all steps found in the documentation page for the plug in. Keeping in minds that the CRM is third party and no information can be found for it online.